# SFML no longer working

Tags: c++, linker, dependencies, sfml

Following a complete reformat and an upgrade from Visual Studio 2012 to 2015, my program will not compile and spits linker errors at me. I have looked at the paths, linker and whatnot, and it looks just as it should for it to work, I have looked at my code as well in the referenced classes, but they are all set up with proper includes and namespaces too.

All files, including the SFML libraries and my own source code, was kept on my dropbox before i reformatted, so no files have changed folders, which i have double-checked as well.

Entire project is written in C++

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Starfall, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>AnimatedSprite.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class sf::RectangleShape & __cdeclsf::RectangleShape::operator=(class sf::RectangleShape &&)" (__imp_??4RectangleShape@sf@@QEAAAEAV01@$$QEAV01@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl AnimatedSprite::AnimatedSprite(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct HandlerContainer *)" (??0AnimatedSprite@@QEAA@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PEAUHandlerContainer@@@Z)
1>DynamicSprite.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class sf::RectangleShape & __cdecl sf::RectangleShape::operator=(class sf::RectangleShape &&)" (__imp_??4RectangleShape@sf@@QEAAAEAV01@$$QEAV01@@Z)
1>CuboidDrawable.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class sf::ConvexShape & __cdecl sf::ConvexShape::operator=(class sf::ConvexShape &&)" (__imp_??4ConvexShape@sf@@QEAAAEAV01@$$QEAV01@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl CuboidDrawable::CuboidDrawable(class CuboidShape,struct HandlerContainer *)" (??0CuboidDrawable@@QEAA@VCuboidShape@@PEAUHandlerContainer@@@Z)
1>C:\Users\Riilu\Dropbox\Starfall\Code and shit\Starfall\x64\Debug\Starfall.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Did you also upgrade SFML libraries to VS2015? Read [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-vc.php) - **"You must download the package that matches your version of Visual C++. ... If there's no SFML package compiled for your version of Visual C++, you will have to build SFML yourself"**

Comment: Oh, haha, I didn't realize, sorry about that.

Comment: @mvidelgauz Write this as an answer not a comment :) .

Comment: @Lehu I doubt OP will ever even login with the same username to accept this answer (to clean "unanswered questions" list), but I followed your request :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you also upgrade SFML libraries to VS2015? Read [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-vc.php) - "You must download the package that matches your version of Visual C++. ... **If there's no SFML package compiled for your version of Visual C++, you will have to build SFML yourself"**